# AngularJs + Reset all attributes on a SingleClick and dnt have form tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reset

In AngularJs, I am trying to reset all the attributes ( i.e, Dropdown, CheckBox, RadioButton etc) inside a controller. Trying to built global function for all the Controllers.

**Snippet :-**

```
<div id="first_div" ng-controller="FirstDivController">
  <select id="user_list" ng-options="user in users" ng-model="user_name" >
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="social_medium" data-target="facebook" 
     ng-model="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="social_medium" data-target="twitter" 
     ng-model="">

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="reset_data()">
    <span></span> Reset
  </a>
</div>
```

On a single click, I am trying to reset the all the element values as default, and dnt have any form tag. But I am not getting the way to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about button type reset?

Comment: Question updated now. Please check

Comment: I don't see any reference to your `singleClick` in the code

Comment: if you are using ng-model='user.firstname' and ng-model='user.lastname' then you can set it as user={} in reset logic

Comment: @pyerwin : It's just a camelcase keyword. now updated. 
JayantPatil :- I tried your suggestion but not working.